# Powershell script to add a new row with 4 items to an existing CSV file

Tags: powershell, csv

Forgive my beginner's attempt..
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Here's the layout:

CSV Column Headers:

VENDOR,#PAGES,SENDER,RECIPIENT

DocInc,25,John,Mary

I would like to add a new row under that with:

AcmeInc,30,Bill,Paul

I am using this script (substituting actual data in param for testing):

```
param($Vendor)

param($Pages)

param($Sender)

param($Recipient)

$newRow = $Vendor, $Pages, $Sender, $Recipient

$newRow | Export-Csv -Append -path C:\Files\CSVFILE.CSV
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

and welcome to StackOverflow! You have made a good attempt, and just some minor mistakes, so let's walk through this real quick. We'll start with the `Param()` block. This should be an array of parameters, not multiple `Param()` calls. So it should look like this:

```
param(
    $Vendor,
    $Pages,
    $Sender,
    $Recipient
)
```

That's simple enough, moving on. The `Export-Csv` cmdlet expects to get an object with properties to be able to export, not an array of strings. So we can do this one of two ways. We can either just do string manipulation and output the string, or we can make an object and export it to a csv. We'll go with the latter since that is what you were attempting I think.

First, we make an object:

```
$newRow = [PSCustomObject]@{
    'Vendor'=$Vendor
    '#Pages'=$Pages
    'Sender'=$Sender
    'Recipient'=$Recipient
}
```

Now that we have an object we can just pipe that to `Export-Csv` exactly how you were doing it before. So the completed code looks like:

```
param(
    $Vendor,
    $Pages,
    $Sender,
    $Recipient
)

$newRow = [PSCustomObject]@{
    'Vendor'=$Vendor
    '#Pages'=$Pages
    'Sender'=$Sender
    'Recipient'=$Recipient
}

$newRow | Export-Csv -Append -path C:\Files\CSVFILE.CSV
```

That's what a lot of people would call the "right way" to do this. You can do some string manipulation and just tack the resulting string to the end of your file, but it is unwise to do it this way since there's more to creating a CSV than just joining several strings with a comma. If you are determined to do string manipulation remember that you need to escape quotes before you enclose each value in quotes, and join them with commas.

```
param(
    $Vendor,
    $Pages,
    $Sender,
    $Recipient
)

$Line = '"{0}","{1}","{2}","{3}"' -f ($Vendor -replace '"','""'),($Pages -replace '"','""'),($Sender -replace '"','""'),($Recipient -replace '"','""')

$Line | Add-Content C:\Files\CSVFILE.CSV
```

Comment: Your answer was perfect, worked excellent.  Thank you so much!